# Automatically expand ssrs drildown report while exporting to excel or pdf

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I want to expand the SSRS report automatically when click export button of excel or PDF. Please share any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't happen automatically when you click the export button. If you need something expanded, consider adding a link in your report for the user to click instead. You can make it sort of look like a button - create a textbox and use background color to make it stand out. In this textbox, use a Jump to Report or Jump to URL and connect to another version of the report that is expanded the way you like. Then you can export that. If you use the Jump to URL button, you can use URL Access parameters to render the expanded version of the report automatically to Excel or PDF so the user doesn't have to take that extra step. You can see more about URL Access parameters here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153586

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue is the users are typical non technical and I cannot convince them saying that to click a link/button to get the report expanded. I will try for the other solutions if any.

Comment: If they have to click a button to export to Excel or to PDF anyway, I don't see what the difference is. The link/button I'm proposing does everything in one step - both jump to another expanded report and do the export. The user just sees the end result as a prompt to save the Excel file or the PDF file. It's as simple a solution as you're going to find.

Comment: Hi Stacia, Thank you very much for you time. I could fixed it the way you suggested.